# Android Dev.: How to populate gallery by image URL?

Tags: android, image, url, gallery, photo-gallery

I'm trying to build a gallery where the images within will be pulled from the images URL from a website.  i.e. Instead of doing R.drawable.xxxx.jpg, you use a url to represent the image.

Is this possible?  If so, can you show me an example in code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this might be old post, but hey this library from github might be helpful

[Android Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Also, on Application class, set the option to MaxPriority for better outcome.

Cheers,
Hope this helps...